# pythonでutf-8の意味をもつ文字列を、utf-8にデコードしたい

Tags: python, python3

`あ`はutf-8としては`U+E38182`になりますが、
変数にある`E38182`という文字列を`あ`に変換する方法がわからず詰まっています

```
moto = 'E38182'
u8 = u'' + moto
print(u8.decode('utf-8'))
```

としてみましたが、以下のエラーになります

```
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

対応方法をどなたか教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: `あ` は U+3042 ですよ。それを UTF-8 エンコードすると E3 81 82 です。その辺誤解しているとこの先混乱するだけッス

Comment: なんかxy問題の予感。

Comment: 文字コードの理解が出来ていないことがわかりました.解決したもののそんな状態なので勉強します.ありがとうございました.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u8 = u'' + moto`の行を`u8 = bytes.fromhex(moto)`に置き換えてみてください。

この辺の記事を参考に。
[classmethod fromhex(string)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex)
[bytes.fromhex と bytes.hex](https://qiita.com/masakielastic/items/21ba9f68ef6c4fd7692d#bytesfromhex-%E3%81%A8-byteshex)

Comment: うまくいきました.ありがとうございました.